# SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable() doesn't return all columns?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I ran into an issue when using the GetDataTable() method. I'm trying to return the default SharePoint column "FileRef" in my results to use. I include it in my SPQuery.ViewFields

Query:

```
<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='FileRef'/></IsNotNull></Where>
```

ViewFields:

```
<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Category' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Created' />
```

I can even see it returned in the items.XML but when I call GetDataTable() it is not put in the datatable.

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(spq);
dtItems = items.GetDataTable();
```

Why isn't GetDataTable working correctly? Am I going to have to write my own conversion method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:[Improving SharePoint's SPListItemCollection GetDataTable(), let's get all the fields I need](http://www.myrocode.com/post/2009/05/20/Improving-SharePoints-SPListItemCollection-GetDataTable()-lets-get-all-the-fields-I-need.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... I guess this answers my question, that this function really doesn't return all the fields. I was trying to avoid having to rewrite this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you a better solution

As SPListItemCollection has Xml proeprty that stores all item data, you can use [this XSLT](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/05/29/reformatting-xml-retrieved-directly-from-the-sharepoint-api.aspx) to get data in normal XML format and then create DataSet from XML.

This Idea can be converted to handy extension function:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Balticovo.SharePoint
{
    public static partial class Extensions
    {
        static string sFromRowsetToRegularXmlXslt =
                "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" " +
                 "xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" " +
                 "xmlns:s=\"uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882\" " +
                 "xmlns:z=\"#RowsetSchema\">" +

             "<s:Schema id=\"RowsetSchema\"/>" +

             "<xsl:output method=\"xml\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" />" +

             "<xsl:template match=\"/\">" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;rows&gt;</xsl:text>" +
              "<xsl:apply-templates select=\"//z:row\"/>" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;/rows&gt;</xsl:text>" +
             "</xsl:template>" +

             "<xsl:template match=\"z:row\">" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;row&gt;</xsl:text>" +
              "<xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*\"/>" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;/row&gt;</xsl:text>" +
             "</xsl:template>" +

             "<xsl:template match=\"@*\">" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;</xsl:text>" +
              "<xsl:value-of select=\"substring-after(name(), 'ows_')\"/>" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&gt;</xsl:text>" +
              "<xsl:value-of select=\".\"/>" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&lt;/</xsl:text>" +
              "<xsl:value-of select=\"substring-after(name(), 'ows_')\"/>" +
              "<xsl:text disable-output-escaping=\"yes\">&gt;</xsl:text>" +
             "</xsl:template>" +
            "</xsl:stylesheet>";

        public static DataTable GetFullDataTable(this SPListItemCollection itemCollection)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string xmlData = ConvertZRowToRegularXml(itemCollection.Xml);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlData))
                return null;

            using (System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlData))
            {
                ds.ReadXml(sr, XmlReadMode.Auto);

                if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
                    return null;

                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }

        static string ConvertZRowToRegularXml(string zRowData)
        {
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            XmlDocument tidyXsl = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                //Transformer
                tidyXsl.LoadXml(Extensions.sFromRowsetToRegularXmlXslt);
                transform.Load(tidyXsl);

                //output (result) writers
                using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    using (XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        //Source (input) readers
                        using (System.IO.StringReader srZRow = new System.IO.StringReader(zRowData))
                        {
                            using (XmlTextReader xtrZRow = new XmlTextReader(srZRow))
                            {
                                //Transform
                                transform.Transform(xtrZRow, null, tw);
                                return sw.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

By the way, using this method, you will get, if needed, file attachment URL's (`SPQuery.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true`) not just TRUE/FALSE values as you would get it by using [previously mentioned method](http://www.myrocode.com/post/2009/05/20/Improving-SharePoints-SPListItemCollection-GetDataTable()-lets-get-all-the-fields-I-need.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Janis' answer - I'd remove the bits that do a substring on the ows_ and attempt to remove it, just use:-

```
"<xsl:value-of select=\"name()\"/>" +
```

because SP2010 now includes fields such as ETag which don't being with "ows_" and the solution fails. Very good solution otherwise.